# angular 2 cookies sent withcredentials but can't access them?

Tags: angular, http

When I use `withCredentials` I can see that cookies are sent to the server. But are not shown on chrome developper tools and I can't access them using `documen.cookie`.

*NB: Front and back servers use different ports.*

Comment: The question is tagged AngularJS but the title says Angular 2 - Which one is it? And what's your actual question?

Comment: angular 2. my question is: server returns set-cookie header, angular sends returned cookie in the next request. but I can't see cookie when making document.cookie and I can see it in developer tools of chrome

Comment: _"Front and back servers use different ports"_ That's why. `document.cookie` can only access the "frontend" cookies.

Comment: but I need to access cookies to add csrf token header, what should I do ?

Comment: It has probably http-only set to `true` which prevents it to be accessed by JS.